# How do you determine the order of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$t^5y^{(4)} - t^3y'' + 6y = 0$$

the answer is fourth order, but I don't understand why exactly is it because of $y^{(4)}$? If so, is $y^{(4)}$ equivalent to $y''''$?

also, it says the equation is linear, but how is that possible if the exponent of $t$ is $5$ (and not 1)? Shouldn't a linear equation be of the form $ax + c$?

Comment: ah its '' my bad. y''

Comment: A differential equation is linear if it is of the form $$a_n(t)y^{(n)} + a_{n-1}(t)y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_1(t)y' + a_0(t) y = f(t)$$ where $a_i$ and $f(t)$ are all functions of $t$.

Comment: ah nice thanks.

Comment: isn't ai a constant and not a function of t?

Comment: @GladstoneAsder The definition of a linear DE allows for the $a_i$ to be functions of $t$.

Comment: but what does that mean exactly? can ai = 5 as well as 5t?

Comment: @GladstoneAsder Either of those are valid choices for any $a_i$.  For example, you could have $a_0 = 5$, $a_1 = 5t^2$, $a_2 = 5e^t$, etc, etc

Comment: thanks a lot, i really appreciated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $y'''' = y^{(4)}$. So it's fourth order because the highest order derivative is $4$.

Linear *functions* have the form $ax + c$. This is a linear *operator*: it doesn't eat numbers, it eats functions. So to see it's linear, take two different functions, $f$ and $g$, and a constant $a$, and verify that
$$t^5 (af(t) + g(t))'''' + t^3(af(t) + g(t))'' +6(af(t) + g(t))\\ = a\big( t^5f^{(4)}(t) +t^3f''(t)+6f(t)\big) + \big(t^5 g^{(4)}(t)+t^3g''(t)+6g(t)\big).$$

Comment: another question can you transform the equation into y = ax + c form?

Comment: Instead of thinking of a line as $y = ax + c$, think of it as a function $f(x) = ax + c$. This is a linear equation because, for any numbers $b, x, y$, $f(bx + y) = bf(x) + f(y)$. That's how you should think of this differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  Basically, $y^{(4)}$ is shorthand for $y''''$.  This notation arises because counting little tickmarks is bothersome, to say the least.  For example, imagine if I wanted $\frac{d^{104}y}{dx^{104}}$.  You'd have to draw $104$ little tickmarks, or you could simply say $y^{(104)}$.

And in general, the order of a differential equation is the order of the greatest derivative in the problem.  So, $y^{(4)} = y$ is a fourth-order, and $y' = y$ is a first order.

Regarding linear differential equations:  In determining order of differential equations, we don't care about what $t$ does.  The same is true for determining if a DE is linear or not.  We want a linear combination of the derivatives of the function.  So, the first two examples below are linear, the second two are not:
$$y' + y'' + y = t$$
$$t^4y'' + \cos t + y = 1$$
$$\cos(y'') + y = 3$$
$$(y')^2 + y = t$$
(Note that for the last one, I'm denoting exponentiation, not the order of the derivative.  The difference is the lack of parenthesis in the superscript.)

Answer (score 1):

Its fourth order because the maximum derivative is the fourth, and $y^{(4)}$ is the same as $y''''$.

Its linear because you can write as $f_4(t)y^{(4)}+f_3(t)y^{(3)}+f_2(t)y^{(2)}+f_1(t)y^{(1)}+f_0(t)y+f(t)=0$

Comment: so y'''' = y^(4)?

Comment: and why is it linear?